# Как поправить ошибку в Вебмастере про одинаковый title и description?

Tags: seo, поисковые-системы, яндекс-вебмастер

Что нужно прописать в index.php (главный файл на сервере, по которому доступен домен), чтобы не показывались ошибки про одинаковый title и description у того же самого файла по адресу / и /?

Вот что показывается Яндекс.Вебмастер:
[image]

Comment: Исправьте ссылки на сайт, настройте редирект. Да и там все рекомендации даже написаны

Comment: Что нужно написать в index файл ?